# Get time difference in seconds, between 2 Epoch times, Javascript

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I have 2 Epoch times, e.g. `1673252582, 1673253317`

Now i am trying to calculate Difference in seconds between these two using date-fns: `differenceInSeconds(1673252582, 1673253317)`.

But this is giving me **-0** as result.

Please help.

Comment: const time1 = 1673252582;
const time2 = 1673253317;

const seconds_diff = (time1 - time2)/1000;

// Epochs are just times in milliseconds from 1 January, 1979.

Comment: The difference between those 2 timestamps is less than 1 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the diff by subtracting one timestamp from the other.

If you need it in seconds and current input is in milliseconds, you will need to convert milliseconds to seconds by dividing by 1000.

for example:

```js
const diffInSeconds = (timestampA, timestampB) => {
  //  absolute value added incase you just want the diff but don't care which came first
  return (Math.abs(timestampB - timestampA)) / 1000
}

const res = diffInSeconds(1673256249000, 1673256240000)
console.log(res) // 9
```